# Entity Framework Core - Updates in Parallel with transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, task

I'm fairly new to Entity Framework Core.

I have multiple products which needs to be updated (several fields (see variable `updateFieldList` in my code below). For each update I need to create a change log entry with an stored procedure. This is done by `ExecuteSqlRawAsync`. Unfortunately I need to create the change log entry by stored procedure; it is caused by our ERP system.

The code works fine, if I remove the execution in `Tasks`, but depending on the amount of products to update the whole procedure takes very long (for 533 products it takes ca. 5 min., which is fairly too long). So I had the idea to run the updates in parallel using tasks.

I know, I can not use the same `DbContext` in tasks (as far as I know). So I found this MS article, which I thought, could solve my issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#share-connection-and-transaction

This is my code I'm using currently:

```
public async Task<Result> UpdateProductStatus(List<DTO.QueryResult> productsUpdateList, Vorlauf newProductStatus, string changeReason)
{
    try
    {
        var updateFieldList = new List<FieldUpdate>()
        {
            new FieldUpdate("Prodstat", newProductStatus.Nummer),
            new FieldUpdate("_Date", DateTime.Now),
            new FieldUpdate("_User", Environment.UserName)
        };
        if(changeReason.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
            updateFieldList.Add(new FieldUpdate("Stchinfo", changeReason));
        }
        if (newProductStatus.Log5 == 1)
        {
            updateFieldList.Add(new FieldUpdate("Sperr", (byte)1));
        }
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(Connection.GetImpGgConnectionString());
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<IMP_GG_Context>()
            .UseSqlServer(connection)
            .Options;
        using var context1 = new IMP_GG_Context(connection);
        using (var transaction = context1.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Artikel>();
            foreach (var product in productsUpdateList)
            {
                predicate = predicate.Or(artikel => artikel._Kenn == product.ProductId);
            }
            var products = context1.ArtikelTable.Where(predicate).ToList();
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                var task = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    using(var context2 = new IMP_GG_Context(connection))
                    {
                        context2.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
                        foreach (FieldUpdate fieldUpdate in updateFieldList)
                        {
                            var updateResult = UpdateArtikel(product, fieldUpdate);
                            Changelog changelog = new Changelog(product, fieldUpdate.DatabaseFieldName.ToUpper(), fieldUpdate.OldValue.ToString(), fieldUpdate.NewValue.ToString());
                            string changeLogQuery = changelog.CreateQuery;
                            var parameters = changelog.GetSqlParameterList();
                            var result = _Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(changeLogQuery, parameters);
                            context2.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                });
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            transaction.Commit();
            return new Result(Enums.ResultStatus.Success);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        return new Result(Enums.ResultStatus.Failure, exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + exception.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

The thing with this code is, that no exception occurs, but the data is not being updated at all. What can I try next?

Comment: When you tested the code in the debugger (stepping through the code) using a single record, did it run as you expected?

Comment: Yes, on the product all information is being set, but it seems to be igonring my `context2.SaveChanges()` command.

Comment: try using only 1 context2 not a context for every iteration. 
You can update more then one object and then call SaveChanges(). Further reading: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating

Comment: You cannot use the same connection in parallel. ADO.NET Providers have such limitation.

Comment: @Jeb Thanks for the link. I will have a look at it. But if I use only one `context2` will I then not again into the issue, that I cannot use one instance in multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you update product entity in UpdateArtikel? Maybe it's because you read products from context1 and call SaveChanges for context2. Please, try somthing like this

```
    using(var context2 = new IMP_GG_Context(connection))
    {
        var productEntity = context2.ArtikelTable.Where(p => p._Kenn == product._Kenn).First();
        context2.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
        foreach (FieldUpdate fieldUpdate in updateFieldList)
        {
            var updateResult = UpdateArtikel(productEntity, fieldUpdate);
            Changelog changelog = new Changelog(product, fieldUpdate.DatabaseFieldName.ToUpper(), fieldUpdate.OldValue.ToString(), fieldUpdate.NewValue.ToString());
            string changeLogQuery = changelog.CreateQuery;
            var parameters = changelog.GetSqlParameterList();
            var result = _Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(changeLogQuery, parameters);
        }
        context2.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I mean read entity from the same context. Because EF can't track changes from different contexts.

**UPD**:
As [@dns_nx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3725142/dns-nx) mentioned in comment this solution works fine with Multiple Active Result Sets ([MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets)) enabled, MultipleActiveResultSets=true

**UPDATE FROM OP [@dns_nx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3725142/dns-nx)**

I overlooked the fact that I was working with another `DbContext` (`_Context`) when executing the stored procedure. This means that I now have to open a third `DbContext` (`context3`) for executing the stored procedure. Here is the final working code:

```
...
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    using (var context2 = new IMP_GG_Context(connection))
    {
        context2.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
        var productEntity = context2.ArtikelTable.Where(p => p._Kenn == product._Kenn).First();
        foreach (FieldUpdate fieldUpdate in updateFieldList)
        {
            var updateResult = UpdateArtikel(productEntity, fieldUpdate);
            Changelog changelog = new Changelog(productEntity, fieldUpdate.DatabaseFieldName.ToUpper(), fieldUpdate.OldValue.ToString(), fieldUpdate.NewValue.ToString());
            string changeLogQuery = changelog.CreateQuery;
            var parameters = changelog.GetSqlParameterList();
            using (var context3 = new IMP_GG_Context(connection))
            {
                context3.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
                var result = context3.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(changeLogQuery, parameters);
            }
        }
        context2.SaveChanges();
    }
});
...
```

Comment: Better move SaveChanges out of the loop.

Comment: For a single product your provided solution is working fine. But if I select multiple products I get the error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'` on your new code line `var productEntity = context2.ArtikelTable.Where(p => p._Kenn == product._Kenn).First();`

Comment: And one more notice. You use same transaction for update all products and change logs. Maybe it would be better update all products in one context without tasks, and then update changelogs using tasks but same transaction?

Comment: @EvgeniySenetskiy Sorry, I did not get it fully. Where is the benefit of your idea. Actually one (field-) change does need to create one change log entry. Then I need to double loop all the updates, I think and actually I don't see the benefit right now.